# What type of tool do I need to remove this screw?

Tags: screws, screwdriver

As the title says. I need to remove this type of screw, but don't know what tool to use.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know where can I get the screwdriver for this?

Comment: What is the device that this is on? Make/model as well.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the picture, is the square part projecting out of or depressed into the surrounding material?

Comment: Looks like a proprietary design, used to prevent unauthorized access. You'll likely have to make your own tool, buy/steal one from the manufacturer, or have a dealer/repair shop remove it for you.

Comment: If squarish part is inset, a properly sized screwdriver, standard tip, will jam in there and allow removal. If part is protruding then it is needlenose time. Either way, replace the screws with something reasonable when you put the thing back together. You *may* have to go in again.

Comment: That isn't #2 square drive? @Tester101

Comment: @Mazura Maybe, but it looks slightly rounded and has weird corners. At least to me.

Comment: It is surprisingly hard to tell from the photos if that is a squarish depression or projection.  If it is a depression, it sure looks like a square drive bit will do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need an 8-point socket. It is hard to tell the size from the picture but it looks small, you will probably need one in 1/4" drive. If you want a driver for it, you can get a 1/4" drive socket drive handle.

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's called a safety torx bit. Torx has no pin in the middle.

Comment: That comment was made when a 3rd pic was here. Does it look like a star? If so my answer is correct. I zoomed top pic and I can't see it from that.

Comment: That 3rd pic was an "answer" that was really a question about a different screw, for which you gave an answer. That "answer/question" has been deleted - I don't know if it was made into a separate question or not.